# Can I tune a model after training it? (Convolutional Neural Network & Classification)

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, convolution, image-recognition

I am relatively new to Data Science and I've recently embarked on a project. Long story short, I've trained a CNN model to distinguish between Male and Female genders. However, I wish to **tune my model**. I've **saved the weights and bias of the existing model**.

1. Can I use the current model with weights and bias to **retrain** on augmented data (from the same initial dataset)? I am guessing there are 2 possible outcomes, it tunes the model or it "resets" the weights and bias.
2. Can I perform hyperparameter tuning with RandomSearchCV or GridSearchCV using on my existing model? I believe this will tune the model.

My aim is to reduce overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your questions, let's understand a few points -

1. Model training is nothing but finding the right weights going through the guiding path based on the loss function o/p using y_true and y_pred.

Training starts with random initialization of weights(*definitely following some rules*)

2. Neural Network training is an incremental training approach *i.e. it doesn't see all the data in one go like the DecisionTree*

> *Can I use the current model with weights and bias to retrain on augmented data (from the same initial dataset)? I am guessing there are 2 possible outcomes, it tunes the model or it "resets" the weights and bias*

Yes, learning will continue without any big disruption as augmented images will produce a similar gradient like the real images.

It will not reset, as I said the training is an incremental process.

Any new image which has completely different features can definitely cause a large gradient to flow and might disrupt the weights *but with augmented images, I don't think any such thing should happen*.

> *Can I perform hyperparameter tuning with RandomSearchCV or GridSearchCV using on my existing model? I believe this will tune the model.*

You can do this but you don't have too many hyperparameters left as Model is fixed. You may tune Learning rate.

Comment: I understand the points, thank you. However, I am still a bit confused. Does that mean my model will be more **generalised** after training it with augmented data?

Comment: Yes. Should be. Augmentation is an accepted approach to regularized